# Android - Firebase add to views count?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

So I have a `RecyclerView` which I populate with the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. I retrieve the required data using this code:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HashMap,MViewHolder> adapter1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HashMap, MViewHolder>(HashMap.class,R.layout.list_item,MViewHolder.class,firebase.limitToLast(5)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MViewHolder mViewHolder, HashMap hashMap, int i) {
            mViewHolder.title_txt.setText(hashMap.get("title").toString());
            mViewHolder.body_txt.setText(hashMap.get("body").toString());

            Firebase userRef = new Firebase("https://yournewz.firebaseio.com/users/" + hashMap.get("poster").toString());
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mViewHolder.postedTxt.setText("Posted by: " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            };

            userRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

            mViewHolder.context = (MainFragment)getParentFragment();
            //mViewHolder.postedTxt.setText(poster);
        }
    };

 public static class MViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView title_txt;
    TextView body_txt,postedTxt;
    MainFragment context;

    public MViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title_txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        body_txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.body);
        postedTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.postedBy);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int item = getAdapterPosition();
        int pos = 5 - item;
        Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://yournewz.firebaseio.com/items");
        //firebase.get
        context.GoToStory(postedTxt.getText().toString(),title_txt.getText().toString(),body_txt.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement a view count that will store the amount of 'views' an item has. I want to make it so that when a user clicks on a recyclerview item, it adds a child to the item in the Firebase Database which is as follows:

```
yournews
----items
    ----QLEJCCNGJIDOS (item key)
        ----body: "text"
        ----title: "text"
        ----poster: "UID"
        ----views: "0"
```

Is there a way to get the item key from the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to add 1 to the views child of the item each time it is clicked in the `RecyclerView`?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks. (sorry for the poorly worded question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getRef()`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L150) on `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is what you're looking for.

You can do something like this:

```
protected void populateViewHolder(final MViewHolder mViewHolder, HashMap hashMap, int i) {
    // ...
    DatabaseReference ref = getRef(i);
    String itemKey = ref.getKey();

}
```

Then you have the key of the current item and you can use that to populate your custom logic.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the `int i` in populateViewHolder was the position. Thanks for the help.